# viewControllerが異なる場合のviewの表示階層の制御

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c

UITabBarControllerが保持するviewControllerのviewのsubViewを、
UITabBarControllerのviewのsubViewより手前に表示させたいです。

layer.zPositionやbringSubviewToFront:などは、viewがきょうだい関係には無いこの場合には無効だと思いますが、何か方法があるでしょうか？

Comment: 'UITabBarControllerが保持するviewControllerのviewのsubView'はわかります。'UITabBarControllerのview' は、意味不明です。ですから、全体の質問が、意味不明です。UITabBarControllerは、UIkit標準のカプセル化iViewControllerで、他のViewControllerを抱え込むことはできますが、直接、viewは、もたないのでは。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。UITabBarControllerはUIViewControllerのサブクラスなので,viewを持っています。タブとは違うところにviewを設けていて、その上にviewをドラッグさせるUIをつくろうとしていますが、下になってしまうのです。

Comment: UITabBarControllerのviewを直接、いじるのは、禁じ手なんでは。Appleの検索は、ダメなので、Google で、Humane Interface Guideline iOSで、ひける文書のUIBar ->Tab Bars でAppleが述べている原則に違反しないか、検討が必要だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController が保持している viewController の view も、内部的には UITabBarController の view に addSubView() されているかと思います。
そのため最前面に表示したい view を bringSubViewToFront: で前に出せば解決可能かと思います。

Comment: 折角ご回答いただいたのに一ヶ月以上コメントできず申し訳ございませんでした。試してみましたが、前に出ず試す前と同じ振る舞いでした。

Comment: [self.view.subviews indexOfObject: ... ]でindexを確認したところ、UITabBarControllerのviewのsubViewは5でしたが、UITabBarControllerが保持するviewControllerのviewのsubViewは、bringSubViewToFront:する前も後も9223372036854775807(検索したところ符号つき64ビット整数型の最大値)でした。[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex: ... withSubviewAtIndex: ...] で両者のindexを変更してみようとしましたが、例外発生で落ちてしまいます...。